# How does headScript() view helper work?

Tags: zend-framework, view-helpers

I'm using Zend_View_Helper_HeadScript to add JavaScript code inside the `<head>` tag.

```
$view->headScript()->appendScript($javascript);
$view->headScript()->appendScript($javascript2);
```

This works fine, except that my code is full of `<script>` tags (one for each `appendScript call`). How to add `$javascript2` to the same `<script>` tag? I just want to have one `<script>` tag inside the `<head>`.

What's the difference between `headScript` and `inlineScript`?

Answer (score 2):

Please try

```
$view->headScript()->appendScript($js1)->appendScript($js2);
echo $view->headScript();
```

InlineScript is used if you have to add script inside your `<body>` Tag.

Comment: Thanks, but I use `appendScript()` in different places (custom view helpers).

Comment: @Adrian just out of curiosity why is it that you need to have only one script tag. As far as I know its of no impact other then the code looking a little bit uglier.

Comment: Better readability, easier processing, (a bit) faster execution.

Comment: what will this `$js1` contain?